# Tweets classification

Tags: twitter, machine-learning, text-classification

I'm trying to get into machine learning and so I wanted to try out text classification on tweets. I collected a small sample of tweets, but for me to perform any supervised learning I need to hand label some of the tweets I collected. This is an arduous task when I scale up my data.

Is there any way to perform classification without me hand labeling a large number of tweets?
Or are unsupervised learning better for this task?

Answer (score 0):

Semi-supervised learning methods were created for problems like this. Simplest approach includes you manually labelling few observations, running a supervised learning algorithm on the labeled data to select a classifier to label other observations, and this is repeated.

Comment: About what percentage of the data should I manually label to get decent accuracy for multiclass classification? Since tweets are so diverse I guess there should be at least 10 classes.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure about this. But I remember reading an example in which just 2 observations were labeled and semi-supervised learning was used. So maybe if you starting with 10, then using only the few most significant classifications, then repeating, could do fine.

Answer (score 0):

Tweets are short text. You should try a classifier tailored for short-text classification such as LibShortText: https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libshorttext/

This article explains certain properties of short text (title) vs full-text classification : https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/title.pdf

Classification will always involved labeled data (active learning techniques help with labeling datasets) but you can take advantage of new emerging techniques such as Snorkel (data programming) to alleviate some of the issues: https://github.com/HazyResearch/snorkel